# In SQL, what happens if you try to rollback to a savepoint from another user?

Tags: sql, postgresql, savepoints

If USER1 does some work, adds a savepoint SP1 but does not commit.

Then, USER2 does some other work, and tries to rollback to SP1.

Would there be an error? Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using postgresql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there would be an error.

A savepoint is only visible and valid inside the transaction that created the savepoint.

So a transaction can only rollback to a savepoint that was created in that transaction.